# Check if answer is from specific form

Tags: maxima

I want to check if some maxima input is of a specific form. For example, I want to check if the answer is of the form `A*%e^(B*t)` where A and B are specific real numbers.

If student X gives answer `3*%e^(5*t)`, then it is of this form. If student Y gives answer `sin(t)`, or maybe `y=3*%e^(5*t)` then I can give this student as feedback that his answer is not yet of the correct form.

I was wondering if there exist something like this in maxima.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maxima has several pattern-matching functions that operate on expressions (not strings). I think `defmatch` is suitable here, e.g.:

```
(%i8) matchdeclare ([A, B], constantp);
(%o8)                                done
(%i9) defmatch (match_aexpbt, A*exp(B*t), t);
(%o9)                            match_aexpbt
(%i10) match_aexpbt (5*exp(3*u), u);
(%o10)                       [A = 5, B = 3, t = u]
(%i11) match_aexpbt (sqrt(2)*exp(%pi*z), z);
(%o11)                   [A = sqrt(2), B = %pi, t = z]
(%i12) match_aexpbt (y = 5*exp(3*u), u);
(%o12)                               false
(%i13) match_aexpbt (5*sin(2*u), u);
(%o13)                               false
(%i14) match_aexpbt ((1 + %i)*exp(exp(%pi)*v), v);
                                           %pi
(%o14)                  [A = %i + 1, B = %e   , t = v]
```

In this case I've defined `match_aexpbt` which matches expressions which look like `A*exp(B*t)` where `A` and `B` are constants and `t` is a variable which is supplied.

See the documentation for `defmatch` and `matchdeclare` and also `defrule`, `tellsimp`, and `tellsimpafter`. The pattern-matching functions are a little idiosyncratic but actually pretty useful -- I have used them many times.

If you are interested in checking student's answers, there have been projects based on Maxima for that. Take a look at the [related projects](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/relatedprojects.html) webpage and see in particular [STACK](http://stack.bham.ac.uk/).